# terminator installation on Kali Linux (apt-get error)

Tags: kali-linux, package-management, gnome-terminal

It is my first time using Kali Linux or Linux in general so I typed the command. So, I can install another terminator but I was surprised with a lot of errors the terminator throws

THE COMMAND I ENTERED

```
apt-get install terminator
```

THE ERROR I GOT

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 libkeybinder-3.0-0 python-gi-cairo python-psutil
Suggested packages:
  python-psutil-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 libkeybinder-3.0-0 python-gi-cairo python-psutil terminator
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 410 not upgraded.
Need to get 877 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,558 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libkeybinder-3.0-0 amd64 0.3.2-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 amd64 0.3.2-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-gi-cairo amd64 3.26.1-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-psutil amd64 5.4.2-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:5 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 terminator all 1.91-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/keybinder-3.0/libkeybinder-3.0-0_0.3.2-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/keybinder-3.0/gir1.2-keybinder-3.0_0.3.2-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/p/pygobject/python-gi-cairo_3.26.1-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/p/python-psutil/python-psutil_5.4.2-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/t/terminator/terminator_1.91-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I ALSO TRIED

```
sudo apt update
```

THE ERROR I GOT

```
Get:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
Err:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
Fetched 30.5 kB in 17s (1,823 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
424 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So, please if you have any recommendation or solution I will be grateful and thankful. And please don't downvote or report the question if it not professional instead please help me improve the question.
Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/272848

Comment: Also, try `sudo apt update` before `sudo apt install ...`. That's because these package have probably been upgraded and those versions no longer exist in the target repo.  `apt update` gives you the latest index of what's available on the server.

Comment: I just realized the last line says: `E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update`.  Did you try that?

Comment: If this is your "first time using Kali or Linux", you shouldn't begin with Kali. Kali is not a distribution for beginners.

Comment: @Stewart still I am getting the same error

Comment: When I type  `sudo apt update` I also get many errors

Comment: I also tried `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo apt update`.

Comment: @GAD3R I edited the question and added the output of `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. The invalid signature for Kali Linux repositories.
2. The package index is outdated.

Use the following command to correct the problem:

```
wget -q -O - https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc |sudo apt-key add
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install terminator
```

Comment: Is it okay when it askes for permission to restart multiple times?

Comment: @YUSOFKHAN It is OK to restart the systemd services during the system upgrade.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this issue for 3 nights now... searched countless forums, threads, and groups; read plenty of articles; edited and uninstalled/reinstalled files, etc, and the above answer is the only one that not only correctly explained the issue so I could understand why & how the errors were generated, but actually worked. Thank you @GAD3R.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/423065)